# SoapUI repsonse parsing

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am using groovy script to parse through the response of an API call using SoapUI.

The response i am getting has the following elements in the exact order-

```
<DeviceOS>
<Bids>
<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>2</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Computers</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>32</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Smartphones</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>0</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Tablets</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

</Bids>
</DeviceOS>
```

I want to access each of the BidAdjustment and DeviceName elements and store them in a file. To do this i am using an XML holder object called **holder** and using the code **holder.getNodeValue("//*:BidAdjustment")**.

However, this is just returning the first value (i.e 2 for computers). How do i get the other ones? All the names are the same and thus i cant refer them by different names. Help would be greatly appreciated :) :) Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*I guess you are using a holder from the `com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils` class.*

You are getting for what you are asking, just one node.
You probably should use `def nodes = holder.getDomNodes("//*:DeviceOSTargetBid")` instead.

Then you can iterate over every returned node by the xpath expression.

***UPDATED***

```
def items = holder.getNodeValues("//*:DeviceOSTargetBid")
for (node in items) {    
   node.BidAdjustment.text(); 
   node.DeviceName.text();       
}
```

Some useful documentation:
http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/xml/dom/DOMCategory.html

Or if you prefer to change the way you get the response you can try this way:

```
def rootNode = new XmlSlurper().parseText(
    '''<DeviceOS>
<Bids>
<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>2</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Computers</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>32</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Smartphones</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

<DeviceOSTargetBid>
<BidAdjustment>0</BidAdjustment>
<DeviceName>Tablets</DeviceName>
</DeviceOSTargetBid>

</Bids>
</DeviceOS>''' )

def f = new File('C:/yourFileName.txt')
rootNode.Bids.DeviceOSTargetBid.each(){ s ->
    f << "${s.DeviceName.text()} ${s.BidAdjustment.text()}" + '\n'
}
```

Comment: Could you please share the code of how to iterate over the elements contained in each node and extract their value?

Comment: Not happening bro :( throwing an error stating "No such property: BidAdjustment for class:java.lang.String